# TTS fails to operate and activity fails to launch

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech, eclipse-luna

I've put together an activity that uses the TTS API and code I've used in another project for the same purpose. However, TTS fails to operate and the activity fails to launch all together. I've studied my code and cannot decipher where the problem is. The code matches my other project's code exactly, and the code in the other project works as expected. The log cat data is hard to understand, so hopefully someone in this community can help me find the problem. I think it may be an Android Studio issue. The other project is installed within Eclipse Luna. It's got to be the TTS code because the activity in question was launching just fine before I added the TTS code. I've attached my code and the log cat info.

ADDITIONAL INFO: Perhaps it's the behavior I am trying to implement. I am attempting to send a saved string to the TTS engine upon the loading of the activity into view, using a timer to launch TTS 1 second after the view initializes. I'm not sure, however, if I can launch an instance of TTS without a button press to execute it. My other project, which works, calls the TTS engine on the click of a button...???

```java
public class InfoGreetView extends ActionBarActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

TextView infoGreetPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoGreetPrompt);
TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
Timer timer = new Timer();
Timer timer2 = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask;
TimerTask timerTask2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_greet_view);

    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this,this);

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibrator.vibrate(500);

            startPlayback();

        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask,1000);


}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){

    if (textToSpeech != null){

        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();

    }
    super.onDestroy();

}

@Override
public void onInit(int status){

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){

        int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.messagePlaybackInterrupted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.messagePlaybackInterrupted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }


}


public void startPlayback(){

    String infoGreetViewPrompt = infoGreetPrompt.getText().toString();
    HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "completed");
    textToSpeech.speak(infoGreetViewPrompt, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashRender);

}

@Override
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId){

    timerTask2 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent displayGuestMessageView = new Intent(InfoGreetView.this, GuestMessageView.class);
            startActivity(displayGuestMessageView);

        }
    };
    timer2.schedule(timerTask2, 1000);

}
```

Comment: You should add logs to your code at the different key points, and edit your question to add the resulting logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Hooray! I figured out what the issue was. First of all, my dependencies in Android Studio were not completed. I had to add the **compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'** jar; all I had in there was **compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'**. I believe this is why TTS was not operating.

Second, I had tried to mimick Xcode's viewDidAppear method along with a timer so that TTS would begin when the view appeared, within onResume(). However, this was not working. The Log Cat said something about not binding to TTS. So, I threw my timer into onCreate() and instead of throwing my startPlayback() method separately from a call within my timer, I simply added the code within startPlayback() into my timer. Why? For some reason, the call wasn't happening. Here is my new and perfectly operating code!

```
public class InfoGreetView extends ActionBarActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener, TextToSpeech.OnUtteranceCompletedListener {

TextView infoGreetPrompt;
TextToSpeech textToSpeech;
ImageView attentionButton;
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info_greet_view);

    attentionButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.attentionButton);
    infoGreetPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoGreetPrompt);
    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(this,this);

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            String text = infoGreetPrompt.getText().toString();
            HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
            myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "completed");
            textToSpeech.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashRender);

        }
    };

    timer.schedule(timerTask,500);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){

    super.onDestroy();

    if (textToSpeech != null){

        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();

    }

}
@Override
public void onInit(int status){

    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){

        int result = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.languageNotSupported, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
    else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.messagePlaybackInterrupted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    textToSpeech.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId){

    Intent displayGuestMessageView = new Intent(InfoGreetView.this, GuestMessageView.class);
    startActivity(displayGuestMessageView);

}
```

}